# Why doesn't this series converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

given series:
$$x^2+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^3}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^4}+\ldots$$

in the interval $[-1,1].$

I tried to break the problem in two cases:1)$x=0$, in which case the series is zero.

2)$x\neq0$: I solved the G.P. and i got $(1+x^2)$ which is bounded and then i concluded that the series should converge uniformly.

But the answer is given as not.So where am I mistaken?

Comment: Naive comment: Can't you write $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=1+\frac{1}{x^2}$. And if $x=0$ is checked, $x^2\ (\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}-\frac{1}{1+x^2})=1+x^2-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$

Comment: Fix $n$ and use the formula for the sum of a Geometric series to compute $R_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty {x^2\over (1+x^2)^k}$. Then show $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}R(x)=1$. What does this tell you with regards to uniform convergence?

Comment: If you want not to use the theorem on the continuity of the sum but apply to the definition of u.c., see Courant/John _Introduction to Calculus and Analysis I_ Springer (1989), pag.533 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple fact that it converges to a bounded function doesn't imply uniform convergence.

Moreover, if the series would converge uniformly, the limit would be a continuous function. Is your limit continuous at $0$? What does this mean?

Comment: Even if it converges to a continuous function doesn't imply uniform convergence.